# Incoming APIs for OSI (Open Solver Interface)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, coin-or-cbc

We want to use COIN-OR for a research project alongside some other optimization programmes and it would be lovely if we could use a standardizes API, in the best case a web-based one, to start up all the solvers from a single point.

Sadly I was unable to find any information about accessing OSI from another point, so I hope that someone here has experience what is possible and which options are impossible.

The general maillist couldn't help so far since my registration is still open and I'm not sure if the whole project is still maintained.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have had some success with writing models using Sonnet (https://sourceforge.net/projects/sonnet-project/) which is a C# wrapper around OSI. We were able to write large and complex models and solve them with any of the solvers which work with OSI by changing a run-time switch. The modelling style is around variables and constraints which is much simpler for us than the 'matrix of coefficients' style. That was a few years ago so it may not be fully up to date; but it is open source and fairly clean structured code so relatively easy to update if necessary.